# std::find_if for custom objects returns bad iterator when vector has at least 1 element

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

So I have a vector of objects of type Player. If I try to use std::find_if on that vector and use a lambda expression that return true only if the name if the player is a name I want to check against, it will work the first time if the vector is empty (as in the iterator is nullptr), but once I add a Player object in the vector, the find_if will return an iterator filled with random, bad data.

My code:

```
    auto player = find_if(m_playerList.begin(), m_playerList.end(), [name](Player& p)
    { 
        return p.Name == name;
    });

    if (player._Ptr != nullptr)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    else
    {
        Player newPlayer;
        newPlayer.Name = name;
        m_playerList.push_back(newPlayer);
    }
```

So in the first iteration of this function, the player is nullptr, because the vector didn't contain any elements. In the second iteration, if I search by the same name, it finds it in the vector, however if I search by a different name, it returns an object with mangled, random data and the check "if (player._Ptr != nullptr)" passes.

Question is, what causes this? Am I checking the "player" object properly to figure out if the find_if actually found a valid object in the vector?

Comment: What is `player._Ptr`? Are you using your own vector class?

Comment: also `find_if` returns `end()`, not `nullptr` if the element is not found.

Comment: _Ptr is the pointer to the actual object. It's part of std::vector::iterator

Comment: Borgleader, in that case how would I check if the data found is valid, and not end() ?

Comment: @AlexVS2013 it's a part of your particular implementation and there are no requirements on it.

Comment: ... player != end, no offense but thats obvious from what i said before, it returns end if its not found so if its found it wont be end.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: 
error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Player>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: [It very much does work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f8f0752b67450c2).

Comment: @AlexVS2013 That is an implementation detail of the standard library you are using. It is not guaranted to have a member called _Ptr, which means you if you rely on this your code is not portable.

Comment: I wonder what implementation this is that makes the `_Ptr` member publicly accessible…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you wrote isn't portable because it uses implementation-specific `_Ptr` member of `vector::iterator`, and  therefore there are no requirements on that member to be `nullptr`. Change

```
if (player._Ptr != nullptr)
```

to

```
if (player != m_playerList.end())
```